# How to comparison local and global variables in function python

Tags: python-3.x, function, global-variables, local-variables

I'm trying to comparison global variable inside def function. After that I want to update global variable.

Unfortunately I get output
SyntaxError: name 'name_1' is used prior to global declaration

Is it possible to comparison global and local variables inside function?

```
name_1 = ""
 
 
def get_names(name_a):
    while name_a == name_1:
        name_a = input("Ener first name: ")
        if name_a != name_1:
            print("Your name is : ")
 
        elif name_a == name_1:
            print("you not enter name")

    global name_1
    name_a = name_1
 
get_names(name_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are using `name_1` before `global name_1`.
Try like this :

```py
name_1 = ""
 
 
def get_names(name_a):
    global name_1
    while name_a == name_1:
        name_a = input("Ener first name: ")
        if name_a != name_1:
            print("Your name is : ")
 
        elif name_a == name_1:
            print("you not enter name")

    name_a = name_1
 
get_names(name_1)
```

(EDIT)
And if you want to print the name don't forget :

```py
print("Your name is : ", name_a)
```

instead of :

```py
print("Your name is : ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your advice is a game changer for me! Thanks a lot. Finally code is look like as below

'''
name_1 = ""

def get_names(name_a):
global name_1
while name_a == name_1:
name_a = input("Enter first name: ")
if name_a != name_1:
print("Your name is : " + name_a)
name_1 = name_a
break
elif name_a == name_1:
print("you not enter name")

get_names(name_1)
print(name_1)
'''